# qml listmodel parse row

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a ListModel in Qml which is filled dynamically.

I would like to know how can I retrieve information regarding a row from the model when I do myModel.get(i). This returns an object but I do not know how to extract information from it. In the docs I saw all example with myModel.get(i)."something". But I do not have any field to call, I would like something like :

```
function getValue(i,columnIndex)
{
    var obj =  myModel.get(i)
    var requestedValue = obj[columnIndex]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not have any field to call", how did you write your `ListModel` ?

Comment: ListModel { id:myModel }

Comment: and how do you populate it ?

Comment: When a user clicks on a row in a table view, the row is processed and the result is appended to myModel.

Comment: My point is that you should have roles to call, columnIndex doesn't make sense for a `ListModel`.

Comment: the view which is using the model is a TableView. i need to select values at a given column...

Comment: Inspect the object with: `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))`  That should print you out a json representation of what that object is, to start with.

Comment: I could use the output of stringify and I took the values from the object using the parameters from the output ( myModel.get(i).some_param ).

Answer (score 1):

When you want to access the attributes you must do it through the name of that attribute. For example

```
ListModel {
        id: myModel
        ListElement {
            title: "Moby-Dick"
            author: "Herman Melville"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer"
            author: "Mark Twain"
        }
}
```

You can access it in two ways:

```
{your Model}.get({index}).title
{your Model}.get({index})['title']
```

Comment: when i define the model i do not have any ListElement. But as I mentioned before I could do it by inspecting the JSON and I took the fields from there.